# Show that $d(X,Y) \geq d(X,Z) \implies f(X,Y) \geq f(X,Z)$ where $d$ is Euclidean distance function.

Tags: general-topology, inequality

Let us consider arbitrary three points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $X,Y,Z$ by $$X=(x_1,x_2); \> Y=(y_1,y_2); \> Z=(z_1,z_2).$$ Now consider the Euclidean distance function $d(X,Y)$ as $$d(X,Y)= \sqrt{ (x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}.$$ Now consider an another function $f(X,Y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $$f(X,Y)=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|.$$ Now can we show that if $$d(X,Y) \geq d(X,Z) \>\>\> \text{ holds then } f(X,Y) \geq f(X,Z) \>\> \text{ holds}.$$ So basically we need to show $$d(X,Y) \geq d(X,Z) \implies f(X,Y) \geq f(X,Z).$$ So how can we prove this? Is there any counter-example which contradicts the argument?  May be we can use any topological argument which shows that these two metrics are equivalent?
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample:

Let $X=(0,0)$, $Z=(\frac12\sqrt2,\frac12\sqrt2)$ and $Y=(1,0)$.

Then $d(X,Y)=d(X,Z)=1$ but $f(X,Y)=1<\sqrt2=f(X,Z)$.

---

For proving that two metrics $d$ and $F$ are equivalent it is enough to show that constants $a,b>0$ exist with $d(X,Y)\leq a\cdot F(X,Y)$ and $F(X,Y)\leq b\cdot d(X,Y)$ for all $X,Y$.

For $a$ you can take $1$ here and for $b$ you can take $2$.